# Orthogonality of Jacobi polynomials and the parameters

Tags: special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

Consider the Jacobi polynomials  denoted by $ P_n^{(\alpha,\beta)}(x) $ corresponding to the weight function $w(x) = (1+x)^{\alpha } (1-x)^ {\beta} $ defined on $(-1,1)$.   Why is that the condition $ \alpha > \beta > -1 $ and $ \alpha + \beta + 1 $ be a non-negative integer is imposed  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition is used to ensure that the [Jacobi polynomials are orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_polynomials#Orthogonality).